# How to change the severity level (INFO, ERROR, WARNING, etc.) of log message in Fluentd based on some keyword in the log payload?

Tags: regex, logging, kubernetes, fluentd, google-kubernetes-engine

I really hope somebody would help me out with this question, as I have been trying to figure it out for days.

I have container running in kubernetes in GKE. In /var/log/containers/my_container.log, I have something like this (among some other logs with different formats):

```
{"log":"17-Oct-2017;04:36:29.744 : [main] [server:] [id:] [yt:] ERROR no.myproject.service.Server - call failed for some reason\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-10-17T04:36:29.750702216Z"}
```

This log appears on Stackdriver (Fluentd output in GKE) as INFO log and like:

```
23:02:32.000 17-Oct-2017;04:36:29.744 : [main] [server:] [id:] [yt:] ERROR no.myproject.service.Server - call failed for some reason
```

So

```
23:02:32.000
```

is added to it (which is the normal behavior of Stackdriver). I will refer to this format as format 2.

As this log message actually is an ERROR log message (based on its payload content) I want it to appear as ERROR in Stackdriver (Fluentd).

I am trying:

```
<filter reform.**>
  type parser
  format /^(?<time>\d{2} [^\s]*) : (?<message2>[^ \]]*)\] (?<message3>[^ \]]*)\] (?<message4>[^ \]]*)\] (?<message5>[^ \]]*)\] (?<severity>\w)\s+(?<log2222>.*)/
  reserve_data true
  suppress_parse_error_log false
  key_name log
</filter>
```

hoping to get the severity of the message change to ERROR and also getting the content of the [..] fields in the log as some new key/values (in this case message2: main, etc).

But after adding this filter to my config file, the output logs are still as before and I don't see any change.

What am I missing? When I am writting my Regex pattern, I am not sure if I actually should consider the "log" field of the message in the log file in kubernetes or the one that I called format 2 (with the time added to it - on Stackdriver).

I would really appreciate any advice, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the tool you're using, but it looks like first part of your regex does not match the exact format of the prefixed time in your log string.

Actually `\d{2}` will only match 2 digits.

To match the entire time prefix you may use `(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{3}` instead.

One additional point regarding severity: you wrote `(?<severity>\w)` which captures only one word character. You may use `(?<severity>\w+)` to match several characters.

Your regex would then become:

```
^(?<time>(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{3} [^\s]*) : (?<message2>[^ \]]*)\] (?<message3>[^ \]]*)\] (?<message4>[^ \]]*)\] (?<message5>[^ \]]*)\] (?<severity>\w+)\s+(?<log2222>.*)
```

That [demo](https://regex101.com/r/o5lu2j/1) shoes a match.

Comment: Thanks very much. Now I'm capturing the severity from the payload in the output. I have one more question.  I was also expecting that in the output the new fields of message2 to message 5 and log2222 will be added, but no new field is added. How can I extract some data from the log text-payload and get it as a new extra  field in the output (like "message2: [main]" in the above example)?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know your tool, so I'm not sure it will help but, if you can specify replacement strings, you could then use `${severity} message2: ${message2}` as a replacement. You'll then get `ERROR message2: [main`. See the new version [here](https://regex101.com/r/o5lu2j/2).